# i have array of users how to find what ones are Disabled

Tags: active-directory, powershell-2.0

What i am trying to do = Return all Disabled accounts in certin Groups and store them in a Veriable i can use to search with VM view to detach Persistant Drives from disabled users.

```
$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like "view_*"}
$rtn = @()
    ForEach ($Group in $Groups)
    {
        $rtn += (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "$($group.name)" -recursive)
    }
$dis = @()
foreach ($user in $rtn) 
    { 
        $dis += (get-aduser -filter {enabled -eq $false})
    }
```

i belive this works for me but i need to know is there a Better way to do this? cause this takes a lot of time with couple thousand users

Comment: ok this does not work i'm a fool thats going to search all of AD for any disabled users but do it for each entry in the &rtn group

Comment: `Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -eq "group name"}| Get-ADGroupMember | Get-ADUser | ? { $_.Enabled -eq $false }`       this works great for one group but will not do multiple groups.

Comment: This i Feel is the BEst way to do this for Multiple Groups Let me know if any one else has a better way please.

 `$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like "view_*"};$rtn = @(); ForEach ($Group in $Groups){$rtn += (Get-ADGroupMember -identity "$($group.name)" -recursive|%{Get-ADUser -Identity $_.distinguishedName -Properties Enabled | ?{$_.Enabled -eq $false}} )}`

$rtn hold all your Data of disabled accounts in your groups now you can export it or continue to use it in another command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's any overlap in your group membership (users in multiple groups), you'll be calling `Get-ADUser` multiple times for the same user. This will slow you down and return duplicate data you'll have to filter out.

You can do this without the `Foreach` loop and array building, just a single pipeline will work. Linebreaks added for formatting clarity.

```
$rtn = get-adgroup -filter {name -like "view__*"}|`
    foreach-object {Get-ADGroupMember $_ -recursive}|`
        select-object -expandproperty distinguishedname  -unique|`
        get-aduser -Properties enabled|`
        where-object {$_.enabled -eq $false};
```

This returned 37 distinct users across 9 groups. Across multiple runs, the execution time was anywhere from 1.1 to 2.5 seconds.

The method in your answer returned 60 users across those same 9 groups - with a lot of duplicates (because they weren't filtered out). Across multiple runs, the execution time was anywhere from 1.7 to 3.5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This is feel is the best way to accomplish what i set out to do

```
$groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like "view_*"}
$rtn = @()
ForEach ($Group in $Groups)
{
    $rtn += (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "$($group.name)" -recursive | %{Get-ADUser -Identity $_.distinguishedName -Properties Enabled | ?{$_.Enabled -eq $false}} )
}
```

if any one has a better way of doing this please let me know.